# Is there any way to use decimal datatype (with 28 precision digits) with scipy.integrate in Python?

Tags: python, scipy

I am currently trying to solve a system of ODE with scipy.integrate in Python using the command solve_ivp. Is there any way to integrate this system using decimal datatype? I need more than 16 digits of precision. For instance, I need the output with 28 digits.

Comment: Where possible those `scipy` solvers pass the task to compiled libraries; thus restricting floats to the conventional `float` and `double`.  `mpmath` allows more precision, and may have some useful solvers.  But my only experience with `mpmath` is as an addon to symbolic `sympy`.

Comment: May I ask why and for what you need that amount of precision? The most precise physical measurements are only made to 16 digits or so.

Answer (score 0):

`Solve_ivp` uses Python routines internally with Numpy arrays (except for the linear solves and for the LSODA method which calls a Fortran livrary). Numpy is limited to double-precision, so you won't be able to achieve more precision than that.

I believe the Julia language is able to use quad-precision natively in all its algorithms.